# Does Conversion rates affect the profit earned?

Tags: arithmetic

About $~\$100~$ were given to me as an initial investment. I converted them to *INR* and traded with it in buying stocks and also selling stocks. I am now left with say $~$*Rs.*$6000~$ today. As all of you are aware that *USD* prices varies from day to day, I am in a fix as to understand that I really made any profit or not.

My questions are

1. How to know whether I made any profit or loss?
2. How to calculate my profits if any?
3. Is there any inverse relationship between *USD* and *INR*? In the sense, will a increase in conversion rates, increase *USD* and decrease *INR* values

Any insight will be appreciated

Comment: How much INR did you get, when you converted 100 USD ?

Comment: 1 USD = 61.85 Indian Rupee when I converted

Answer (score 1):

**Ad 1)**

Your initial investment (in rupee) is

$ 100\text{USD} \cdot \frac{61.85 \ \text{INR}}{ 1\text{USD}}=6,185 \ \text{INR}$.

The (absolute) profit is then $6,000 \ \text{INR}-6,185 \ \text{INR}=-185 \ \text{INR}.$

This profit is negative, thus you have a loss of $185 \ \text{INR}$

And your relative profit is $\frac{6,000 \ \text{INR}-6,185 \ \text{INR}}{6,185 \ \text{INR}}\approx -0.03=-3\%$

**Ad 2)**

I think you can conclude the general formula.

**Ad 3)**

If you convert USD in INR, than you have the conversion rate $\frac{x \ \text{INR}}{ 1\text{USD}}$. You get x rupees for 1 dollar. If the dollar increase, you get more rupee for one dollar. Thus x has to be increased. You can also say, that the rupee decreases.

If the dollar decreases, you get less rupee for one dollar. Thus x has to be decreased. You can also say, that the rupee decreases.

---

If you convert INR in USD, than you have the conversion rate $\frac{y \ \text{USD}}{ 1\text{INR}}$. You get y dollars for 1 rupee. If the ruppee increases, you get more dollars for one rupee. Thus y has to be increased. You can also say, that the dollar decreases.

If the ruppee decreases, you get less dollars for one rupee. Thus y has to be decreased. You can also say, that the dollar increases.